# расчет расстояния между векторами numpy

Tags: python, numpy, оптимизация

[image: taeget]Я недавно начал использовать numpy и пока что не являюсь опытным пользователем, нужны ваши советы) Есть две матрицы А и В, каждая строчка в которых - это координаты определённого вектора (по сути, есть два типа атомов и наборы их координат). Количество атомов в каждой матрице(то есть количество строк каждой матрицы) в районе 10000. Но в дальнейшем, возможно, придётся делать расчеты для нескольких сотен тысяч атомов. Каким способом (в плане быстродействия и оптимального использования расчетных ресурсов) лучше всего найти все расстояния между каждым вектором матрицы А и каждым вектором матрицы В?

Пока что написал такую функцию, которая вычисляет расстояния и возвращает **количество** расстояний, меньших заранее заданной длины (defaultLength). Но мне кажется, что это не самый быстрый способ расчёта, возможно ли как-то ускорить код?

```
def Bond(a, b, defaultLength): #a и b - матрицы с координатами атомов A и B

    def Length(x):
        return np.sqrt(x[0]**2 + x[2]**2 + x[2]**2)

    i = 0 

    for row in b:
        c = a - row
        d = np.apply_along_axis(Length, axis=1, arr=c)
        for item in d:
            if item < defaultLength: i = i + 1

    return i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как раз для этого существует функция [scipy.spatial.distance.cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist).

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

distances = cdist(A, B)
```

Для входящих матриц размерности `A(mA, n)` и `B(mB, n)` результирующая матрица будет иметь размерность `(mA, mB)`.

Comment: А если её скорости не будет хватать, то я как-то писал тут о либах, которые массово и быстро считают матрицы расстояний, можно будет поискать )

Comment: @CrazyElf, может добавите свой ответ со ссылками? Я "по быстрому" не нашел тот ваш ответ...

Comment: Да я тоже не нашёл. Мне вообще было обидно, несколько моих хороших ответов погибли из-за удаления пользователей, которым я отвечал. Может и этот ответ среди них, я уж не помню. Хотя я не один раз отвечал, но пока не нашёл тоже.